# Failed to write cache file "/var/www/myapp/app/cache/dev/classes.php" when clearing the cache

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed Symfony 2.0.7 on Ubuntu 11.10. I have this problem:

I changed the permissions of the `cache` e `logs` directories using the following commands:

```
chmod 777 -R cache
chmod 777 -R logs
```

and all functions as I was expecting.

Then I made:

```
app/console cache:clear
```

> Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
>
> permissions of cache/dev change to 755 and symfony cannot write in that:
>
> RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/myapp/app/cache/dev/classes.php".
>
> in /var/www/myapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1079
>   at ClassCollectionLoader::writeCacheFile() in /var/www/myapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1017
>   at ClassCollectionLoader::load() in /var/www/myapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 682
>   at Kernel->loadClassCache() in /var/www/myapp/web/app_dev.php line 23

How can I solve this apparent bug in Symfony 2?

Comment: I avoided this issue by adding `--no-warmup` when clearing the cache so the `dev` folder won't be created by the CLI user. Then, first time you request a page within your browser, the `dev` folder is created by the `www-data` user.

I ended using the solution posted by Federico Gallo, below.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

See the *Setting up Permissions* sidenote in the [Configuration and Setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) section. Use the ACL approach with `setfacl`.

e.g.

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

(where `apache` is your HTTPD user)

Comment: when i type `setfacl` it says `command not found` how can i get rid of it

Comment: @Hunt, install the `acl` package.

Comment: for me it says: setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 3

Answer (score 7):

Well, I'm using `setfacl` to avoid that issues but I still having problems.
**I'm working on a standard user directory** so this do not work for me:

```
APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

If you too, do this: (as privileged user if necessary of course )

```
sudo rm -rf app/cache app/logs
```

Then as NORMAL user create both directories and then apply the commands below as NORMAL user too (without sudo):

```
exit (from root if necessary)
mkdir app/cache app/logs

APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
setfacl -R -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
setfacl -dR -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Note: remember that there are two spaces between `-d\` and `-f1`

Good luck!

Comment: Instead of `exit` you should run `sudo -k` to leave sudo privileges. `exit` also closes the console.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The user I'm talking about is a standard user. So it's not added to the sudoers. That's why I did su and exit

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just do as root user:

```
sudo -u apache app/console ca:cl
```

apache - this will vary depending on the owner your web directory. defaults to apache assuming you are using apache for your web server.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your posts I got to this page

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Then I did this:

HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var

And it solved my problem