# symfony2 : failed to write cache directory

Tags: symfony

I have had to use the

```
app/console cache:clear  command
```

to solve a problem when generating an entity.

I am now unable to load my homepage on :

```
  http://localhost/projet_etienne/web/app_dev.php
```

it says :

> RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/projet_etienne/app/cache/dev/classes.php".

I don't understand much about this cache business!

In my `app/cache` folder, I got a `dev`, a `dev_new`, a `dev_old` folder. Is that normal?

the

```
app/console cache:clear
```

generates by the way a :

> [ErrorException]
>   Warning: rename(/var/www/projet_etienne/app/cache/dev,/var/www/projet_etien
>         ne/app/cache/dev_old): Directory not empty in /var/www/projet_etienne/vendo
>        r/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearComm
>        and.php line 77

please help!

Comment: Check cache folder persmisions. It must be writable. You can do: chmod 777 -R app/cache/

Comment: thanx so much ! that was simply this ...but it is not always easy to identify the source of the problem when not being extremely familiar with symfony nor linux

Comment: chmod 777 is a bad idea.  So many people using linux just gran 777 permissions on something that a specific process needs to write rather than setting the needed permissions for that specific user.  For this particular file, run `ps aux | grep apache` to see what user is running the apache process and then granting ownership via `chown -R apache-user cache` would suffice better than granting rwx for all users.  Be sure to `chmod u=rw cache` afterward to prevent execution as the process does not require those permissions.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

For a GOOD and definite solution see the `Setting up Permissions` section in  `Installing and Configuring Symfony` section :

> Setting up Permissions
>
> One common issue when installing Symfony is that the app/cache and
>   app/logs directories must be writable both by the web server and the
>   command line user. On a UNIX system, if your web server user is
>   different from your command line user, you can try one of the
>   following solutions.
>
> 1. Use the same user for the CLI and the web server
>
> In development environments, it is a common practice to use the same
>   UNIX user for the CLI and the web server because it avoids any of
>   these permissions issues when setting up new projects. This can be
>   done by editing your web server configuration (e.g. commonly
>   httpd.conf or apache2.conf for Apache) and setting its user to be the
>   same as your CLI user (e.g. for Apache, update the User and Group
>   values).
>
> 2. Using ACL on a system that supports chmod +a
>
> Many systems allow you to use the chmod +a command. Try this first,
>   and if you get an error - try the next method. This uses a command to
>   try to determine your web server user and set it as HTTPDUSER:
>
> ```
> $ rm -rf app/cache/*
> $ rm -rf app/logs/*
>
> $ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
> $ sudo chmod +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
> $ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
> ```
>
> 3. Using ACL on a system that does not support chmod +a
>
> Some systems don't support chmod +a, but do support another utility
>   called setfacl. You may need to enable ACL support on your partition
>   and install setfacl before using it (as is the case with Ubuntu). This
>   uses a command to try to determine your web server user and set it as
>   HTTPDUSER:
>
> ```
> $ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
> $ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
> $ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
> ```
>
> For Symfony 3 it would be:
>
> ```
> $ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
> $ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache var/logs
> $ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache var/logs
> ```
>
> If this
>   doesn't work, try adding -n option.
>
> 4. Without using ACL
>
> If none of the previous methods work for you, change the umask so that
>   the cache and log directories will be group-writable or world-writable
>   (depending if the web server user and the command line user are in the
>   same group or not). To achieve this, put the following line at the
>   beginning of the app/console, web/app.php and web/app_dev.php files:
>
> ```
> umask(0002); // This will let the permissions be 0775
>
> // or
>
> umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
> ```
>
> Note that using  the ACL is recommended when you have access to them on your server
>   because changing the umask is not thread-safe.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

source : 
[Failed to write cache file "/var/www/myapp/app/cache/dev/classes.php" when clearing the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449345/symfony-2-cacheclear-bug)

Comment: That cache:clear bug stack-overflow answer to that question is exactly what I have been looking for for quite a while!

Comment: If you're on debian/ubuntu, `apt-get install acl` to use `setfacl`

Comment: This is the one. ~ Ian Brown, Stone Roses.

Comment: For those using Symfony 4 and pasting the commands into their terminal: the `var/logs` folder has been changed to `var/log`.

Comment: for symfony 4 this overhead is taken car of by default : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Answer (score 27):

Most likely it means that the directory and/or **sub-directories** are not writable. Many forget about sub-directories.

**Symfony 2**

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs
```

**Symfony 3 directory structure**

```
chmod -R 777 var/cache var/logs
```

### Additional Resources

[Permissions solution by Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) (mentioned previously).

[Permissions solution by KPN University](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep1/installation#ep1-install-permissions) - additionally includes an screen-cast on installation.

Note: If you're using Symfony 3 directory structure, substitute `app/cache` and `app/logs` with `var/cache` and `var/logs`.

Comment: This is the solution to use with the new version of Symfony directory structure

Answer (score 15):

If the folder is already writable so thats not the problem.

You can also just navigate to `/www/projet_etienne/app/cache/` and manualy remove the folders in there (dev, dev_new, dev_old).

**Make sure to SAVE a copy of those folder somewhere to put back if this doesn't fix the problem**

I know this is not the way it should be done but it worked for me a couple of times now.

Comment: and thanx so much for you help ...and telling me there's nothing wrong in deleting all these cache files

Comment: Is that negative or positive? Because deleting cache files never gave any problems to me

Comment: The actual problem here is that these sub-directories are not writable. Instead of deleting, set them to writable `chmod -R 777 /app/cache` etc...

Comment: I see bad practices, zizoujab answer is better I think

Answer (score 13):

You probably aborted a clearcache halfway and now you already have an app/cache/dev_old.

Try this (in the root of your project, assuming you're on a Unixy environment like OS X or Linux):

`rm -rf app/cache/dev*`

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you forgot to change the permissions of app/cache app/log

I'm using Ubuntu so

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache
sudo chmod -R 777 app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u::rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

I move the whole directory from my Windows installation to a unix production server and I got the same error. To fix it, I just ran these two lines in unix and everything started to run fine

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*
```

Answer (score 1):

i executed:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

and got something like that:

```
root     28147  0.0  5.4 326336 27024 ?        Ss   20:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28150  0.0  1.3 326368  6852 ?        S    20:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28151  0.0  4.4 329016 22124 ?        S    20:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28152  0.1  6.0 331252 30092 ?        S    20:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28153  0.0  1.3 326368  6852 ?        S    20:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28154  0.0  1.3 326368  6852 ?        S    20:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28157  0.0  1.3 326368  6852 ?        S    20:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
user     28297  0.0  0.1  15736   924 pts/4    S+   20:12   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

so my user with no access turned out to be `www-data` thus i executed commands:

```
sudo chown -R www-data app/cache
sudo chown -R www-data app/logs
```

and it solved access errors.

> Never-ever use unsecure 777 for solving specific access probles:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache
sudo chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

Answer (score 1):

if symfony version less than 2.8

```html
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/*
```

if symfony version great than or equal 3.0

```html
sudo chmod -R 777 var/cache/*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you face this error when you start Symfony project with docker (my Symfony version 5.1). Or errors like these:

> Uncaught Exception: Failed to write file "/var/www/html/mysite.com.local/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml"" while reading upstream

> Uncaught Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/mysite.com.local/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainerDeprecations.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied" while reading upstream

Fix below helped me.

In Dockerfile for nginx container add line:

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

In Dockerfile for php-fpm container add line:

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

Then remove everything in directories "/var/cache", "/var/log" and rebuild docker's containers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this acl cmd, next time the files inside var are created it will have the r/w/x permission for www-data user.

```
cd var 
rm -rf *
cd ..
setfacl -d -m u:www-data:rwx var
```

Cmd explanation:

```
setfacl -> Set acl command    
-d -> default behavior    
-m -> modify 
u:www-data: -> for user 
rwx -> adding permissions  
var -> on the folder
```