# Symfony 2 fatal error on cache directory

Tags: symfony

I ssh to my VPS where there is a vagrant box that runs a symfony project.

When i try to access the project i am getting the error:

```
`Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file` and

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could not create cache directory`
```

I have tried fixing file permissions as mentioned here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

and even changed `chmod` to 777. But still getting same error.

I also tried everything there: [symfony2 : failed to write cache directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211829/symfony2-failed-to-write-cache-directory/24271739)

It just won't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

My VPS is running ubuntu 16.04 and vagrant is latest version with image ubuntu/trusty

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Apache check your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file and find your entry for your website in there. Check to see what user Apache is running the site as. You'll want to make sure the directories and files that make up your Symfony app belong to that user and the group the user is in as well. If you are logged in as root and are in the your Symfony directory you can run:

```
chown -R user:group *
```

to change all the files and directories to that user and group. Note to replace user and group in the command above with the actual username and group.

If you still have troubles after you've found the user apache is running as, try removing your symfony files completely (if it is a fresh project that you haven' been working on) and rebuild it while you are superuser'd (su) as that user. You probably built your project as root or another user.

Comment: so my problem is that i am using vagrant, and in the vagrant box i am logged in as `ubuntu` and apache is running as `www-data`. should i set chown to `www-data:www-data`?

Comment: You can try, yes. If all fails you can change it back.