# Symfony can't write in cache folder on CentOS 7 even with the right permissions

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, permissions, centos

Symfony cannot write in cache folder even i give full permissions to that folder

```
chmod 777 -R /path/to/symfony/var
```

But I am always getting these error

> Cache directory "/path/to/symfony/var/cache/dev" is not writable.

I am on Centos 7 and I use nginx and php7

I never had this problem on Ubuntu or Windows. It's just when i moved my application to CentOS

One suggest to me to run those commands on the var folder

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /path/to/symfony/var
systemctl restart nginx
```

This solution worked once. But after a while i got the same problem.
I tried to re-run tose commands but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: try the solutions found here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211829/symfony2-failed-to-write-cache-directory>? it might help you

Comment: In mac, chmod -R 777 /folder/path works and not chmod 777 -R /folder/path. Is it the issue

Comment: check under which user the php-fpm worker(s) (I assume) is(/are) running, also make sure that when updating the code and running composer and running any console command in your symfony project, that it's run with the very same user. Almost every composer command will refresh the cache thus probably resetting the folder permissions. also, I hope you're not running symfony on production server with env=dev.

Comment: @Chilarai Not a good practice. BTW it didn't work as i mentioned on the question

Comment: @Jakumi I am actually on my dev machine :) and i use the same user for nginx and php-fpm. Also the composer is launched with the same user. I posted a solution. the problem seem to be related to the SELinux systems. Thx man

Comment: @raedbaaziz didn't work for me :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue.
Here is how.

First, Nginx and php-fpm are running using the ***nginx*** user. This user is created automaticlly when installing Nginx.

On the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
```

And on the `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
...
...
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode  = 0660
```

Second the permissions on the symfony app are set to 755 and the owner is changed to nginx user/group (The user Nginx and php-fpm are using)

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /path/to/symfony

sudo chmod 0755 -R /path/to/symfony
```

Then, I run two commands. The first is to ennable the httpd connections
And the second allows the httpd process to read and write on the ***/path/to/symfony*** folder

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /path/to/symfony
```

Finanlly, restarting the Nginx service

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```